# How to Compare the data and set a variable

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE registration 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONT_ID NUMBER(10,0); 
    COMM_ID NUMBER(10,0);(Can have null values Nullable)
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Contact 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FirstName CHAR(30 BYTE)
   LastName CHAR(30 BYTE)
);

CREATE TABLE Communication 
(
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FirstName CHAR(30 BYTE)
   LastName CHAR(30 BYTE)
);
```

I have a registration table with `RegistratonId`, `Contact_Id`, `CommunicationId`, `Remark`.

And a `Contact` table

```
ContactID   FirstName   LastName
```

And a `Communication` table

```
CommunicationId   FirstName   LastName
```

I need to derive a condition like For a particular registration ID if the Firstname and LastName of Contact table is same as the Firstname and LastName of Communication table set a variable as ismatching. If comm id is null by ismatching can be set to true

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is **NOT** a database; it is a client application use to talk to a database (and can talk to many different RDBMS). Please [edit] the question and tag which database you are using. If it is Oracle then your code is not valid as Oracle does not support the `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword (from Oracle 12, you would need to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` before that version you would need a sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of database you use (and didn't specify), it looks as (outer) join along with `case` expression.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  registration (id, cont_id, comm_id) as
  3    (select 1, 10, 20 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 11, 21 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 12, null from dual
  6    ),
  7  contact (id, firstname, lastname) as
  8    (select 10, 'Little', 'Foot' from dual union all
  9     select 11, 'Scott', 'Tiger' from dual union all
 10     select 12, 'Michael', 'Jackson' from dual
 11    ),
 12  communication (id, firstname, lastname) as
 13    (select 20, 'Little', 'Foot' from dual union all
 14     select 21, 'Pixie', 'Dixie' from dual
 15    )
 16  select
```

Query:

```
 17    r.id reg_id,
 18    t.firstname ||' '|| t.lastname contact_name,
 19    m.firstname ||' '|| m.lastname comm_name,
 20    --
 21    case when t.firstname ||' '|| t.lastname = m.firstname ||' '|| m.lastname then 'yes'
 22         else 'no'
 23    end as ismatching
 24  from registration r join contact t on t.id = r.cont_id
 25                 left join communication m on m.id = r.comm_id;

    REG_ID CONTACT_NAME    COMM_NAME    ISMATCHING
---------- --------------- ------------ ----------
         1 Little Foot     Little Foot  yes
         2 Scott Tiger     Pixie Dixie  no
         3 Michael Jackson              no

SQL>
```

In Oracle, its SQL doesn't support Boolean datatype up to version 23c (I don't have it; do you?) so (as this example was ran in Oracle 11g) I chose to return a *string* for `ismatching` column.

Comment: Concatenating first and last names before comparison can lead to false matches if someone has the first and last names `X Y` and `Z` and someone else has the first and last names `X` and `Y Z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT r.*,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   contact t
                INNER JOIN communication m
                ON (   t.firstname = m.firstname
                   AND t.lastname  = m.lastname)
         WHERE  t.id = r.cont_id
         AND    m.id = r.comm_id
       )
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS ismatching
FROM   registration r
```

Which, if you have the sample data (correcting your DDL statements for invalid syntax and assuming that you are using Oracle 12 or later to support `IDENTITY` columns):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Contact 
(
  Id        NUMBER(10,0)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  LastName  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
);

CREATE TABLE Communication 
(
  Id        NUMBER(10,0)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  LastName  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
);

CREATE TABLE registration 
(
  Id      NUMBER(10,0)
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
          NOT NULL
          PRIMARY KEY,
  CONT_ID REFERENCES contact, 
  COMM_ID REFERENCES communication
);

INSERT INTO contact (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT 'Alice', 'Abbot' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 'Baron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 'Count' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 'Duke'  FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO communication (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT 'Carol', 'Count' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 'Baron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice', 'Abbot' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', 'Earl'  FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO registration (cont_id, comm_id)
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

| ID | CONT_ID | COMM_ID | ISMATCHING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | true |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | false |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | true |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | true |
| 5 | 4 | 4 | false |

---

If you want to display the names as well then use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT r.id,
       r.cont_id,
       t.firstname,
       t.lastname,
       r.comm_id,
       m.firstname,
       m.lastname,
       CASE
       WHEN t.firstname = m.firstname
       AND  t.lastname  = m.lastname
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS ismatching
FROM   registration r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN contact t
       ON t.id = r.cont_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN communication m
       ON m.id = r.comm_id;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | CONT_ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | COMM_ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | ISMATCHING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Alice | Abbot | 1 | Carol | Count | false |
| 4 | 3 | Carol | Count | 1 | Carol | Count | true |
| 3 | 2 | Beryl | Baron | 2 | Beryl | Baron | true |
| 1 | 1 | Alice | Abbot | 3 | Alice | Abbot | true |
| 5 | 4 | Debra | Duke | 4 | Emily | Earl | false |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T_gGDC-Q)